# Google Sheets, multi-tab, multi-criteria if statements

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a staff allocation sheet for our production teams so that management can see (graphically) the peaks and troughs for each department. I've anonymised the data and shared it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140w_v_ApksXH2q7h_dK5Iglm0VOTF1Zk9fq9jPxF5BM/edit?usp=sharing

What I am attempting to achieve is to have the week commencing dates across the top, the employees down the left (Based on a unique list of employees form the department tabs) and the individual cells populated with the relevant show number (I've manually entered the first two employees).

I had done this successfully by having hidden proxy columns for each show that pull a start and end date from the department sheet via and indirect lookup. Where this falls down is if an employee works on a production at two separate times, e.g. all of May and all of August but not between those months.

I initially attempted a series of nested ifs:

```
=if(and(indirect($A3&"!$B:$B")=$B:$B, 
indirect($A3&"!$E:$E")<=AK$2, 
indirect($A3&"!$F:$F")>AK$2,
indirect($A3&"!$C:$C")="SHOW #1"
),1,
if(and(indirect($A3&"!$B:$B")=$B:$B, 
indirect($A3&"!$E:$E")<=AK$2, 
indirect($A3&"!$F:$F")>AK$2,
indirect($A3&"!$C:$C")="SHOW #2"
),2,
if(and(indirect($A3&"!$B:$B")=$B:$B, 
indirect($A3&"!$E:$E")<=AK$2, 
indirect($A3&"!$F:$F")>AK$2,
indirect($A3&"!$C:$C")="SHOW #3"
),3,
. . . 
if(and(indirect($A3&"!$B:$B")=$B:$B, 
indirect($A3&"!$E:$E")<=AK$2, 
indirect($A3&"!$F:$F")>AK$2,
indirect($A3&"!$C:$C")="SHOW #17"
),17,
0)))))))))))))))))
```

Hoping that this would calculate in each cell and return the correct result, however this did not work, that's when I discovered if() doesn't work with ranges in this context! I've effectively hit a wall on this.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious in this and would appreciate any help!!!

Comment: So I spent last night re-assessing how I was approaching the issue. I ended up with a slightly inelegant solution; In each department sheet I have calculated the show number based on the beginning/end date and nominated show. I have then conditionally formatted the cells so that the text is always the same colour as the background. I have then used a maxifs() statement on the summary page to pull through the highest show number for each date for each person and then used conditional formatting based on the cell contents. Not pretty or elegant, but it works.

Comment: Clarification 1) Are you building "Overview" from "Lighting" sheet, or vice versa? (Given that "Costume" and "Sound" sheets also come into play). 2) How many months in advance/arrears at any time? 3) What is the significance of bands of colour on "Overview"? I wonder if a script would be another option. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435604/google-apps-script-for-creating-normalised-data-from-unnormalised-data-in-google) (ignore the title) is similar in terms of having to take data from one sheet and re-arrange and transpose it on another.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz. 1) The intention is to draw data from 'lighting','costume', etc. to the overview. 2) Usually we are looking at calendar years, so usually a 12 month period. 3) The colours correspond to the project being worked on. I had thought about scripting but it's over a work network that occassionally doesn't like gscripts. I've got it working for now but I'll keep tinkering to streamline it, that Q&A is interesting.